# How to replace `&` in one of POST's value parameter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is what I have in `textarea` using `tinyMCE`:

```
helloóóó
```

I get content from textarea using `tinyMCE` and parse it to my current string:
  action=update&range=settings&id=content_home&content=helloóóó

And when I send this via `POST` to server, my `content` value ends just after `hello`, when there is `helloóóó`.

Can I workaround this somehow? Is there special method for this?

This is how I build the string:

```
var textarea = $(this).parent().find('.tinymce').first()
if (textarea.length) {

    var content = tinyMCE.get(textarea.attr('id')).getContent();
    data += '&content=' + content;
}

$.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    url : url,
    data : data,
    dataType : "json",
    success : function(back) {}
});
```

Comment: Do you want to receive the HTML (hello&oacute;&oacute;&oacute) or the text (helloóóó) on your server?  How are you getting the value for the content param?

Comment: yes, there may be everything including html tags... I am getting the value on the server using `$_POST`.

Comment: How are you building the string?

Comment: You need to show your code that's sending the parameter, so we can see what you're doing wrong.

Comment: @epascarello updated the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well as the other answer pointed out you need to use encodeURIComponent

```
data += '&content=' + encodeURIComponent(content);
```

but a better option is just put your data into an object and let jQuery handle it for you.

```
var data = {
   action : "update",
   range : "settings"
   /* your other fields */
};
data.content = content;

$.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    url : url,
    data : data,
    dataType : "json",
    success : function(back) {}
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to URL encode the values.  Try using the encodeURIComponent() method.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent

Answer (score 1):

`&oacute;` is the html encoded version of `ó`. You can decode it with [`html_entity_decode`](http://php.net/html_entity_decode).

I'm not sure why the data would be HTML encoded though, that seems like a bug. I would expect it to be URL encoded. It will be decoded for you when your receive the data. At the very least it needs to be URL encoded once, HTML encoding is optional.

```
// url encoded:
action=update&range=settings&id=content_home&content=hello%C3%B3%C3%B3%C3%B3
// url encoded and html encoded:
action=update&range=settings&id=content_home&content=hello%26oacute%3B%26oacute%3B%26oacute%3B
```

Comment: It's not a buggy behavior from the editor. The content is html encoded because is comes from a WYSIWYG editor. The OP is the one creating the URL... he has to encode the content using `encoreURIComponent` himself. `theUrl += '&content=' + encodeURIComponent(contentFromTinyMce);`

Comment: Yes I see he updated his answer. It doesn't explain why the string is HTML encoded though. - Oh wait, it's tinyMCE, that explains everything :P